# Insert RDD having JSON Object to HBASE table using Phoenix

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am creating a 'RDD' newData by getting data from REST API using 'Scala'. Content of RDD is 'JSON' object as shown below:

JObject(List((activities-hrt,JArray(List(JObject(List((date,JString(2018-12-21)), (value,JObject(List((customHrtRtZns,JArray(List())), (hrtRtZns,JArray(List(JObject(List((max,JInt(88)), (min,JInt(30)), (name,JString(Out of Range)))), JObject(List((max,JInt(123)), (min,JInt(88)), (name,JString(Fat Burn)))), JObject(List((max,JInt(150)), (min,JInt(123)), (name,JString(Cardio)))), JObject(List((max,JInt(220)), (min,JInt(150)), (name,JString(Peak)))))))))))))))))

I want to put this RDD data into a 'HBASE' table using 'Phoenix'. I need to decide the corresponding 'Phoenix' table structure too. Below is the 'Phoenix' table structure I have created:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "HRT"(
    "id" INTEGER,
    "activitiesHrt"."dateTime" VARCHAR(32),
    "value"."customHrtRtZns" VARCHAR(32),
    "hrtRtZns"."max" INTEGER,
    "hrtRtZns"."min" INTEGER,
    "hrtRtZns"."name" VARCHAR(32),
    CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY ("userid")
);
```

Along with inserting data from RDD to above table, I also need to insert incrementing sequence number in ID column for the purpose of primary key. I tried below code:

```
import org.apache.phoenix.spark._

sc.parallelize(newData)
.saveToPhoenix(
"HEART",
Seq("id","date","customHrtRtZns","max","min",
"name"),

zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)
```

But getting an error given below:

```
import spark.implicits._
<console>:116: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: Seq[?]
               sc.parallelize(newData).saveToPhoenix(
                              ^
<console>:124: error: not found: value zkUrl
               zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)
               ^
import spark.implicits._
<console>:116: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: Seq[?]
               sc.parallelize(newData).saveToPhoenix(
                              ^
<console>:124: error: not found: value zkUrl
               zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)
               ^
```

I have checked insertion to above table using hardcoded values which is working fine. Any suggestions on how to insert using RDD along with incresing sequence number in PK column.

Comment: why you are using `sc.parallelize(newData)`, your `newData` is already a `RDD[String]`. The second error says that there is no `zkUrl` defined in the scope, so use `val zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)`.

Comment: Thanks @vindev. I understand the piece that newData us RDD and I should directly use newData.SaveToPhoenix. However zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer) worked fine when I inserted hardcoded values in the table. Now I am getting 'JAVA heap space' error if using 'val zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer).- or 'zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)' which I believe is a different unrelated issue altogether.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could update your question with the current error/problem that you getting.

Comment: Below is current error:
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at scala.reflect.internal.Names$class.enterChars(Names.scala:70)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Names$class.body$1(Names.scala:116)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Names$class.newTermName(Names.scala:127)
 at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.newTermName(SymbolTable.scala:16)
 at scala.reflect.internal.Names$class.newTermName(Names.scala:135)
 at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.newTermName(SymbolTable.scala:16)
 at scala.tools.nsc.ast.parser.Scanners$Scanner.finishNamed(Scanners.scala:200)
Its a truncated message.

Comment: Heapspace resolved, now getting below errors.

If I use 'val zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer). –' below error:

import spark.implicits._
<console>:98: error: illegal start of simple expression
        val zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)
        ^

If I use 'zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)' then below error:

import spark.implicits._
<console>:115: error: value saveToPhoenix is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
               newData.saveToPhoenix(
                       ^
<console>:123: error: not found: value zkUrl
               zkUrl = Some(phoenixServer)
               ^